# Python tkinter issues using grid() because pack() is already used while it is not

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to write a script that updates an HTML file with the values entered, this script is divide into 2 python files each updating a specific element but then both are called in a third script. Running each one alone works fine and without any errors but when running both of them from the third script I am always getting the error

```
File "/Users/bechara/Desktop/coronaReady/python_program/update_stat_page.py", line 8, in <module>
    number=NewNumbers()
  File "/Users/bechara/Desktop/coronaReady/python_program/updating/update_numbers.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.title_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2484, in grid_configure
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
```

I have searched both scripts and in no one I have used the pack() method, I have just used grid().
This is the first code, which works fine when used on it's own:

```
from pandas import read_csv, melt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class Graph():
    def __init__(self, country):
        self.in_file=read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv")
        self.in_file_1=self.in_file
        self.in_file_2=self.in_file
        self.in_file_3=self.in_file
        self.leb_file=self.in_file_1.loc[self.in_file_1["Country/Region"]==country,:]
        self.leb_file=self.leb_file.drop(columns=["Lat", "Long", "Province/State"])
        self.leb_file=melt(self.leb_file, id_vars=["Country/Region"])
        self.leb_file=self.leb_file.value.values
        self.file=open(f"/Users/bechara/Desktop/coronaReady/python_program/data/data_corona_{country}.csv", "w")
        self.file.write(str(self.leb_file))
        self.file.close()
        self.file=open(f"/Users/bechara/Desktop/coronaReady/python_program/data/data_corona_{country}.csv", "r")
        self.data=[]
        self.data=self.file.read()
        self.data=self.data.split()
        self.data_len=len(self.data)
        for self.a in range(self.data_len):
            try:
                self.data[a]=int(self.data[self.a])
            except:
                if self.data[self.a]=="[":
                    self.data[self.a]=0
                elif self.data[self.a].endswith("]")==True:
                    self.data[self.a]=int(self.data[self.a][:-1])
        plt.plot(self.data, color="#ff0000")
        plt.xlabel("days since 22/01/2020")
        plt.ylabel("Total cases")
        plt.savefig(f"/Users/bechara/Desktop/coronaReady/python_program/images/data_corona_plot_{country}.png", bbox_inches="tight")
        plt.clf()
```

And here is the second code which also works fine when used on it's own:

```
from tkinter import Label, Tk, Entry, Button
from webbrowser import open as webopen

class NewNumbers(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NewNumbers, self).__init__()
        webopen("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
        self.title_label=Label(text="Enter The Numbers To Update The\nStatistics Page", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 20), fg="#000000")
        self.title_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.world_total_label=Label(text="World Total Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.world_total_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.world_total_entry=Entry()
        self.world_total_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="e")
        self.world_deaths_label=Label(text="World Death Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.world_deaths_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.world_deaths_entry=Entry()
        self.world_deaths_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.world_reco_label=Label(text="World Recovered Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.world_reco_label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.world_reco_entry=Entry()
        self.world_reco_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.world_active_label=Label(text="World Active Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.world_active_label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.world_active_entry=Entry()
        self.world_active_entry.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="w")

        self.white_space=Label(text="")
        self.white_space.grid(row=5)

        self.lebanon_total_label=Label(text="Lebanon Total Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.lebanon_total_label.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.lebanon_total_entry=Entry()
        self.lebanon_total_entry.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.lebanon_deaths_label=Label(text="Lebanon Deaths Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.lebanon_deaths_label.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.lebanon_deaths_entry=Entry()
        self.lebanon_deaths_entry.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.lebanon_reco_label=Label(text="Lebanon Recovered Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.lebanon_reco_label.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.lebanon_reco_entry=Entry()
        self.lebanon_reco_entry.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.lebanon_active_label=Label(text="Lebanon Active Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.lebanon_active_label.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.lebanon_active_entry=Entry()
        self.lebanon_active_entry.grid(row=9, column=1, sticky="w")

        self.white_space=Label(text="")
        self.white_space.grid(row=10)

        self.iran_total_label=Label(text="Iran Total Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.iran_total_label.grid(row=11, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.iran_total_entry=Entry()
        self.iran_total_entry.grid(row=11, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.iran_deaths_label=Label(text="Iran Deaths Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.iran_deaths_label.grid(row=12, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.iran_deaths_entry=Entry()
        self.iran_deaths_entry.grid(row=12, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.iran_reco_label=Label(text="Iran Recovered Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.iran_reco_label.grid(row=13, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.iran_reco_entry=Entry()
        self.iran_reco_entry.grid(row=13, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.iran_active_label=Label(text="Iran Active Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.iran_active_label.grid(row=14, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.iran_active_entry=Entry()
        self.iran_active_entry.grid(row=14, column=1, sticky="w")

        self.white_space=Label(text="")
        self.white_space.grid(row=15)

        self.japan_total_label=Label(text="Japan Total Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.japan_total_label.grid(row=16, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.japan_total_entry=Entry()
        self.japan_total_entry.grid(row=16, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.japan_deaths_label=Label(text="Japan Deaths Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.japan_deaths_label.grid(row=17, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.japan_deaths_entry=Entry()
        self.japan_deaths_entry.grid(row=17, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.japan_reco_label=Label(text="Japan Recovered Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.japan_reco_label.grid(row=18, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.japan_reco_entry=Entry()
        self.japan_reco_entry.grid(row=18, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.japan_active_label=Label(text="Japan Active Cases: ", font=("Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", 15), fg="#000000")
        self.japan_active_label.grid(row=19, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.japan_active_entry=Entry()
        self.japan_active_entry.grid(row=19, column=1, sticky="w")

        self.white_space=Label(text="")
        self.white_space.grid(row=20)

        self.update_bttn=Button(text="Update Numbers", command=self.update_values)
        self.update_bttn.grid(row=21, column=1, sticky="e")

    def update_values(self):
        self.world_total=self.world_total_entry.get()
        self.world_deaths=self.world_deaths_entry.get()
        self.world_reco=self.world_reco_entry.get()
        self.world_active=self.world_active_entry.get()
        self.lebanon_total=self.lebanon_total_entry.get()
        self.lebanon_deaths=self.lebanon_deaths_entry.get()
        self.lebanon_reco=self.lebanon_reco_entry.get()
        self.lebanon_active=self.lebanon_active_entry.get()
        self.iran_total=self.iran_total_entry.get()
        self.iran_deaths=self.iran_deaths_entry.get()
        self.iran_reco=self.iran_reco_entry.get()
        self.iran_active=self.iran_active_entry.get()
        self.japan_total=self.japan_total_entry.get()
        self.japan_deaths=self.japan_deaths_entry.get()
        self.japan_reco=self.japan_reco_entry.get()
        self.japan_active=self.japan_active_entry.get()
        print("Values Succesfully Updated")

        html_stat_code=f"""
        <!DOCTYPE html> etc...
        """
        self.stat_code=open("/Users/bechara/Desktop/coronaReady/website/stats_page/stats_page.html", "w")
        self.stat_code.write(html_stat_code)
        self.stat_code.close()
```

But then when calling both of those scripts at the same time with :

```
from updating.update_graphs import Graph
from updating.update_numbers import NewNumbers


lebanon=Graph("Lebanon")
iran=Graph("Iran")
japan=Graph("Japan")
number=NewNumbers()
number.title("Update coronaReady")
number.configure(bg="#ffffff")
number.mainloop()
```

I get the error specified at the beginning of the post.
How can I fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Try moving the three lines `...=Graph(...)` to before `number.mainloop()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As acw1668 commented under my original post putting the Graph() lines after mainloop() fixed the issue